# LaunchDaemon to start server process doesn't work

Tags: macos, launchd

I've tried to write this LaunchDaemon to start my server process. Seem like it should be simple, plutil lint says the file is "OK", but it doesn't launch. I've tried a number of variations and am still failing. It is owned by root as it should be. Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>edu.umich.radmindserver</string>
<key>Program</key>
<string>/usr/local/sbin/radmind</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>radmind</string>
    <string>-w</string>
    <string>0</string>
    <string>-p</string>
    <string>6662</string>
</array>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NetworkState</key>
            <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to include the full path to the radmind binary in your ProgramArguments.

Change:

```
<string>radmind</string>
```

to:

```
<string>/usr/local/sbin/radmind</string>
```

Comment: Thanks Josh I tried that but I get the same behavior: /Library/LaunchDaemons/edu.umich.radmindserver.plist: Operation already in progress

Comment: I also tried your idea of the soma-zone software LaunchControl, which says that the plist is fine, and when I load an unload using it it does indeed start and stop the server process. I am still mystified.